# How do I pass a bitmap of bytes to Cython function? I'm getting garbage values

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitmap, byte, cython

I am doing a subimage search in python and it's obviously too slow.  So in the midsts of converting it to Cython, I found out that it's not so straightforward.  The python side of things shows the bytes as correct (when doing a debugPrint) and the subimage search has been tested and works perfectly.  However, upon doing my first py to Cy conversion, I've hit stumbling blocks.  The only thing I'm doing to convert some python bytes (I think they're bytes.... :o) to a char* pointer is assigning.  Am I losing ownership of the data chunk somehow?

Here is the relevant code:

```
cdef struct PixelsBMP:
    char* data
    int width, height, bands


# Here's how I create the bytes:


cpdef grabPixelsBMP(img=None):
    if img is None:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
    elif isinstance(img, str):
        img = Image.open(img)

    with io.BytesIO() as bytes_io:
        img.save(bytes_io, 'BMP')
        data = bytes_io.getvalue() 
        offset = int.from_bytes(data[10:14], byteorder='little', signed=False)
        data = data[offset:]        # pixels start here

    cdef PixelsBMP px;
    px.data = data
    px.width = img.width
    px.height = img.height
    px.bands = 3 if img.mode == 'RGB' else 4

    return px


# Here's how I access the bytes:
cpdef debugPrintPixels(PixelsBMP px):
    import sys
    cdef char* d = px.data
    print('width:', px.width)
    print('height:', px.height)
    print('bands (alpha=>4):', px.bands)

    cdef:
        int pad_sum = 0
        int pad = nextMult4Pad(px.width * px.bands)
        int x, y, offs

    for y in range(0, px.height):
        for x in range(0, px.width):
            offs = px.width * px.bands * y + px.bands * x + pad_sum
            sys.stdout.write('(' + str(hex(d[offs])) + ',' + str(hex(d[offs + 1])) + ',' + \
                str(hex(d[offs + 2])) + ((',' + str(hex(d[offs + 3]))) if px.bands == 4 else '') + ')')
        print()
        pad_sum += pad
```

What it prints:

```
('width:', 7)
('height:', 3)
('bands (alpha=>4):', 4)
(0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x30,-0x3f,0x4a,0x5c)(0x2,0x0,0x0,0x0)(-0x1,-0x1,-0x1,-0x1)(0x0,0x7,0x0,0x0)()
(0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x30,-0x3f,0x4a,0x5c)(0x2,0x0,0x0,0x0)(-0x1,-0x1,-0x1,-0x1)(0x0,0x4,0x0,0x0)(0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)()
(0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x30,-0x3f,0x4a,0x5c)(0x4,0x0,0x0,0x0)(-0x1,-0x1,-0x1,-0x1)(0x64,0x1,0x0,0x53)(0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)(0x1,0x0,0x0,0x0)()
```

Where it should be an image of black pixels with an alpha channel = 255.

**Am I accessing the bytes correctly using Cython?**

Comment: Since you are getting the bytes from a buffered stream, I wonder whether the Cython buffer docs apply, http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/buffer.html, or the newer memoryviews, http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a memory ownership issue. Your `bytes_io` owns the data that `px_data` points to. You need to allocate some memory and copy over the data:

```
# at the top of your file
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.string cimport memcpy

#replacing px.data = data
cdef char* data_str = data
px.data = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*len(data))
memcpy(px.data,data_str, len(data))
```

When you're done with the struct you then need to free the data. Note that if you pass the struct to Python (e.g. by calling `cpdef grabPixelsBMP` from Python) it generates a dictionary copy of it. You must free the data held by the struct, not the dictionary copy. Memory management in C can be hard...